# In JAVA watchservice api how can i target all drives

Tags: java, watchservice

I am able to Make watch service work in JAVA but i want to make it work in all drives and folders instead of targeting one drive/folder.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class NewClass2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

        Path directory = Paths.get("C:\\");

        WatchKey watchKey = directory.register(watchService, 
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, 
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

        while (true) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println(event.kind());
                Path file = directory.resolve((Path) event.context());
                System.out.println(file + " was last modified at " + file.toFile().lastModified());
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like a very broad question. You want to watch _all_ drives on a pc and the program should be able to pick up whatever drives that are connected, this sounds to me like you need a very Windows (or Linux, or,...) specific API for this. And then you want to watch _all_ folders on all those drives? A bit excessive to watch that many folders. Whether this is correctly understood by me or not I think you need to be a little more specific in what you're asking.

Comment: Possibly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  What is the purpose of monitoring every directory on a system?

Comment: I not need to see every folder but at least all the drive